# Django sqlite content in easy-pdf

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pdf

Django version: 1.11.3

I have stored data in a sqlite database as I want to have displayed in a pdf. I use easy-pdf. I don't know how to parse the data without using render(). How do I do it with get_context_data(). Any suggestions?

This works:

```
def test(request):
all_organizations = Organization.objects.all()
all_tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
context = {'all_organizations': all_organizations, 'all_tickets': all_tickets}
return render(request, 'test/docs/examples/theme/test.html', context)
```

Don't know how to parse all_organizations and all_tickets for use in the easy-pdf:

```
class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
all_organizations = Organization.objects.all()
all_tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
context = {'all_organizations': all_organizations, 'all_tickets': all_tickets}
template_name = "test/docs/examples/theme/hello.html"
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    return super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(
        pagesize="A4",
        title="Test",
        **kwargs
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['all_organizations'] = Organization.objects.all() 
    context['all_tickets'] = Ticket.objects.all()
    context['pagesize']="A4"
    context['title']= 'Test'
    return context
```

try this, and in the template you can access the data using the key names like pagesize, title and all

Comment: Does not work. Does this return context? When it already has returned super?